# how to add a day to date in bash?

Tags: bash, date

For example, I have date: 4 August 1993 and I want to add 348 days to it, how can I do it in bash?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just use the `date` command with `-d` option:

```
$ date -d "1983-08-04 348 days"
Tue Jul 17 00:00:00 BST 1984
```

You can change the output format if you want:

```
$ date -d "1983-08-04 2 days" +%Y-%m-%d
1983-08-06
```

Comment: You can use the OP's date format, too: `date -d "4 August 1993 348 days" +"%d %B %Y"`

Comment: According to man date: `%F full date; same as %Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 19):

In bash on Mac OS X, you can do this:

```
date -j -v +348d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "1993-08-04" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Output: `1994-07-18`

Comment: Been looking for this for a while. I appreciate. I wanted to replace the number "348" with a variable from a bash script. I ended up with `NEXT_DATE=$(date -j -v +$(( incrementDays ))d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "1993-08-04" +%Y-%m-%d)` for anyone else looking to do this.

Comment: Nice! There's a whole slew of formatting options you can use with the Bash `date` command at https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/

Comment: You can't believe how many incorrect answers I've stumbled upon until this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more complex usage of this:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`;
do;
  date -d "2014-02-01 $i days" +%Y-%m-%d;
done;
```

or with pipes:

```
seq 1 5 | xargs -I {} date -d "2014-02-01 {} days" +%Y-%m-%d
```